# Error not found

Tags: bash, character-encoding, sql

I wrote this script to encode / encrypt data from a sql query by changing the names of tables and fields (I played on the ASCII character codes).

```
#! /bin/bash

chr() {
  [ "$1" -lt 256 ] || return 1
  printf "\\$(printf '%03o' "$1")"
}

ord() {
  LC_CTYPE=C printf '%d' "'$1"
}

read -p "saisir votre requete: "  req
printf "%s\n" "$req" > t1.txt

sed -e 's/[;,()'\'']/ /g;s/  */ /g' t1.txt > t.txt

while read line; do 
   for word in "${line[@]}"; do 
    if ! [[ "$word" =~ $(echo ^\($(paste -sd'|' ./req.txt)\)$) ]]; then
     str=$word
     for i in $(seq 1 ${#str}); do
     car=$(echo $(echo $str | cut -c$i))
      x=$(ord "$car")
     let "x= (((x/2) * 3) + 1)"
     var=$(chr "$x")
     echo $str  |  sed "s/\$car/\$var/g"
     done
     sed -i -e "s/$word/$str/g" t1.txt 
     str=""

   fi; 
  done 

done < t1.txt
```

the file `req.txt` contains words like each request as select, insert, update ....

I executed the script but the terminal hangs and displays each word according to the number of characters:

Expl: from was dislayed 4 time

Comment: `while read -a line; do`

Comment: A typo in function `ord()`? you have an extra quote preceding `$1`

Comment: @apaul No, it produce ascii No. of symbol in `$1` variable

Comment: @Costas Yes, my mistake, I thought I read `"'$1"`

Comment: What error is printed?

Comment: more than 10 erreors i will list some of them

Comment: ./essayer: line 24: s: command not found
./essayer: line 26: 0: command not found
select
./essayer: line 24: e: command not found
./essayer: line 26: 0: command not found
select
./essayer: line 24: l: command not found
./essayer: line 26: 0: command not found
select
./essayer: line 24: e: command not found
./essayer: line 26: 0: command not found
select
./essayer: line 24: n: command not found
./essayer: line 26: 0: command not found
nom,
./essayer: line 24: o: command not found
./essayer: line 26: 0: command not found

Comment: @Aomine; I see you edited your code the way I proposed in my answer (please upvote my answer then, since it answered your original problem). If you have new questions with a modified program you should note that in your question. To further debug your script I suggest to use `set -x` instead of letting us do the debug work without even giving us positive votes feedback.

Comment: @Janis thank you but the problem is not solved. the data code desired does not work.

Comment: @Aomine; the answer solved the **original** question! - It's rude to not honor the advice given that solved your original problem. If you have more problems ask new questions. (I see that as your code is written you have a lot more issues; but we are not here to do the debugging for you and create a production software. Instead we can answer questions to concrete problems, as I did; you should thus honor that, otherwise people will not be going to help you further.) - Finally note that "does not work" is not helpful. Continue with `set -x`, as I additionally suggested to track your issues.

Comment: @Janis: I have already honored your work and that of other members and I not want you to do my job. I asked for a little help, I'm not an expert so try sir good help peoples s and especially to speak well. If I were an expert is sure that I will not ask that question to hear such responses.
Finally  thank you again, but I suggest you to listen people carefully because there are other peoples who do not know what you know and there are others who know better than you.

Comment: @Aomine; I guess you have not understood the main point of what I was saying. If you ask Qestion1 (Q1) with Code1 (C1), get Answer1 (A1), then you change Q1 to Q2 and and C1 to C2 according to A1, and continue that way... - that's like letting us do the debugging for you. A question should not be a moving target. - As hinted already; your code is so convoluted that you will likely see many more issues; once we fixed also your Q2 you will come up with Q3. (This is very much like doing the debugging for you. Please try to understand that.)

Comment: Add (as suggested) `set -x` as first command in your script to see where the script hangs. If you need further help to identify the error(s), post the relevant debug information (i.e. the code were it hangs with sufficient context) that the `set -x` directive will produce.

Comment: @janis I understood what you mean and I thank you again for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the output value of a command or function to be assigned use this syntax:

```
 x=$(ord "$car")
 var=$(chr "$x")
```

(The errors you've got because the syntax you used, e.g. `x=ord $car`, will do the following: the variable `x` will get assigned the string `"ord"`, and the variable `x` then made available to the environment of the subsequent command `$car`; but the expanded `$car` is not a command, so you get errors that "s", "0", etc. are not recognized as commands.)